# uncaught TypeError: cannot set property "innerHTML" of null at populate (app.js:13) at app.js:55

Tags: javascript

uncaught TypeError: cannot set property "innerHTML" of null
at populate (app.js:13)
at app.js:55

I entered this code watching a video on youtube from beginning to end:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvk1pFNqXaw&t=293s

heres a link to my repo with everything you'll need to copy, paste, run to see what im facing right now:

```
function populate() {
    if(quiz.isEnded()) {
        //show scores//
    }   else {
        // show question
        var element = $("#question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        // show choices
        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var elementChoice = document.getElementById("choices" + i);
            elementChoice.innerHTML = choices[i];
        }
        showProgress();
    }
}

function guess(id, guess) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function() {
        quiz.guess(guess);
        populate();
    };
}

function showProgress() {
    var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
    var elementProg = $("#progress");
    elementProg.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + "of " + 
quiz.questions.length;
}



function showScores() {
    var gameOverHtml = "<h1>Result</h1>";
    gameOverHtml += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
    var elementQuiz = $("#quiz");
    elementQuiz.innerHTML = gameOverHtml;
}




var questions = [
    new Question("What famous Mathematitian developed a sequential formula 
for the Golden Ratio (Phi)?", ["Issac Newton","Albert Einstein","Leonardo 
Bigollo","Copernicus"], "Leonardo Bigollo"),
    new Question("Who saved Apple from going bankrupt in the '90s?", 
["Michael Dell", "Bill Gates", "Mark Cuban", "Warren Buffet"], "Bill 
Gates"),
    new Question("Though PHP may appear to look simpler than javascript, 
why is js the top scrtipting language?", ["Gives instant-feedback", "It's 
less vulnerable to breach", "Much more control without interferring with 
bandwith", "All reasons shown!"], "All reasons shown!"),
    new Question("What is the Golden Ratio?", ["1.618", "5.1", "0.618", 
"0.3218"], "1.618"),
    new Question("People get shocked when they see PHI is in every great 
picure they see, what's an easy way to tell where phi is?", ["Look for the 
embeded Greek letter, phi.", "Look at the center of the image, youll notice 
that key elements are just slightly off-center.", "console.log to find it", 
"take out a ruler and measure for it."], "Look for the embedded Greek 
letter, phi.")
];

var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

populate();
```

I'm hoping to get some clarity as to why the code wont work even after following a video start to end 3x just to double check....

I have until 5pm 7/25/2019 (today) to finish this!
please help!

also i never knew you can split js into multiple files instead of killing yourself all in one...so that was cool to find out tonight...woulda saved me the past 5 days of headaches but i love this and learning how to do it!

Comment: https://github.com/jim-n-cronic/TriviaGame

LINK TO REPO!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change `document.getElementById("choices" + i)` to `document.getElementById("choice" + i)`

choices should be choice :)

Comment: THANK YOU! however, now i tried with css to make the buttons move to the center but nothing happens, and no error too....plus idk why the question wont show above the buttons where i have an id of "question" to have it move to each question

Comment: question x of y in the corner isnt working either and again it gives no error